# asp.net/vb.nrt select local web.config file only

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-config

I am deploying an asp.net solution written in vb.net, the solution works fine on the localhost server and on my development server. On the live server the solution keeps ignoring the local web.config file and is using one belonging to another persons project which I have no control over.

This is the list of files that  are in the folder I uploaded to the live server:

- imageFolder
- Default.htm
- FormDelete.aspx
- FormDelete.aspx.vb
- thankyou.htm
- web.config

I want my solution to only look at the web.config located in the same folder as it, and not inherit any values from another web.config file. Can this be done?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: May be a stupid question, but did you register a new web or app in IIS?

Comment: Hi Linus thankgs for getting back to me, I already have registered it in IIS

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me some days ago; as I was the owner of them both, I deleted the app I didn't need, and restarted IIS.

Maybe there are some similarities between your app and the other one, or there is some bad redirection, I don't know. In my case, the other app just linked to a test database, that's how I knew there was an issue.